# Singleton class in cocos2d. Access to variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem with access to property of my Singleton Class. 
I have wrote this code: Singleton.h -

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Singleton : NSObject{
    int _wordNumber;
}
+ (Singleton *) sharedSingleron;
@property (readwrite) int wordNumber;
@end
```

Singleton.m file -

```
#import "Singleton.h"
@implementation Singleton
@synthesize wordNumber = _wordNumber;


static Singleton* _sharedSingleton = nil;

+(Singleton *) sharedSingleron{
    @synchronized([Singleton class])
    {
        if (!_sharedSingleton)
            [[self alloc] init];

        return _sharedSingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}
+(id)alloc
{
    @synchronized([Singleton class])
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedSingleton == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        _sharedSingleton = [super alloc];
        return _sharedSingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {

    }

    return self;
}


@end
```

In my First scene I set the wordNumber and go to another scene

```
[Singleton sharedSingleron].wordNumber = wordNum;
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [CCTransitionFlipAngular transitionWithDuration:0.3 scene:[WordsLayer node]]];
```

and in WordsLayer.m I try to get this property

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        int wordNum = [Singleton sharedSingleron].wordNumber;

    }
    return self;
}
```

But wordNum have wrong value. please help me to find a mistake.

Comment: Try to add to properties implementation (in singleton class) NSLog with current value. I think it can help you.

Comment: You never set _sharedSingleton....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe try :

```
+(Singleton *) sharedSingleron{
  @synchronized([Singleton class]) {
    if (!_sharedSingleton)
      _sharedSingleton = [[self alloc] init];

    return _sharedSingleton;
  }
  return nil;
}
```

Comment: it didn't help. When I try to get wordNumber in Singleton class the wordNumber property have bad value too... May be problem in property description?

Comment: oh, This solution is correct. I find a mistake.

Comment: The code you "have written" is from the book "Learning Cocos2D: A Hands-on Guide to Building IOSGames with Cocos2D, Box2D, and Chipmunk", Chapter 7, pages 172-175. I found this post because I encountered the same problem. It appears that this is a mistake in the book. The solution by @YvesLeBorg works for me too.